# VBAで自作DLLを使用できない

Tags: vba, dll

お世話になります。

VisualStudio2017Community(C#)で作成したDLLを、ExcelVBAで
使用しようとしたのですが、うまくいきません。

http://excel.syogyoumujou.com/memorandum/dll_1.html

こちらのサイト様の内容を参考にし、いざExcel側の参照設定までは
たどり着いたのですが、VBAでコードを書こうとしても認識しません。
上記サイト様の『7．VBEにコード入力』のところからです。

実際に実行すると、『ユーザ定義型は定義されていません。』と出ます。

参照設定に追加した後、何かほかにやることがあるのでしょうか。

ご教授ください。

```
namespace Msga
{
    public class MsgClass
    {
        public MsgClass()
        {

        }

        public string getMsg()
        {
            return "Hello World.";
        }
    }
}
```

ちなみに、Excel側は2010です。

Comment: どのようなコードを書いたのでしょうか？ リンク先はVBなのに対し質問文にはC#とあるので、ソースコードの記述内容に問題があるのかもしれません。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。ソースを記述しました。サンプルとして試して書いただけのものなので、大したことはやっていません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参考にされたサイトの「3．プロジェクトの設定」の設定ですが、これだと足りないですね。

1)[ビルド]タブ > [COM相互運用機能の登録] に チェック
2)[アプリケーション]タブ > [アセンブリ情報] > [アセンブリをCOM参照可能にする] に チェック

2)が足りていないので、2)をした後に、ビルドしてみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございました！解決いたしました!!長い間疑問に思っていたことが、やっと解決できました！今後とも何かありましたらよろしくお願いいたします。本当にありがとうございました。