# C#で作ったクラスライブラリをVBAで使用しようとすると『クラスが登録されていません』となってしまう

Tags: c#, vba

VisualStudio2019を使用しています。

https://www.shujima.work/entry/2020/05/10/162356
こちらのサイトをもとに、ExcelなどのVBAで使用できるクラスライブラリ(COM)を
C#で作成してみました。

管理者で作成もし、実際にVBA側に参照の追加もでき、いざ実行すると、『クラスが登録されていません』と
エラーになってしまうのですが、この原因は何なのでしょうか。

原因と対策を訓えてください。
Officeは2016,64bitです。

よろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参照設定のスクリーンショットで、実際のフォルダパスが見えてるので隠したほうがよいのでは。で、そこがOneDriveなのが影響してそうな気がします

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。画像を修正しました。因みに、OneDriveは使用していないはずなのですが…。

Comment: COM関係の属性をつけ忘れていそうな気がしますが、ソースがないと何とも言えませんね。いきなり作りこむより、単純なものを作って呼び出せるか動作確認する所から始めるのがいいかもしれません。この記事の内容が良さそう https://qiita.com/tomochan154/items/1ce33f2aef167c0fed9d

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43904/vba%e3%81%a7%e8%87%aa%e4%bd%9cdll%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84?noredirect=1&lq=1 こちらの質問では既に解決されているようですが、同じようにして作ったものですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘の質問も私が書いたものですが、その時はうまくぃつていました…というか、当時はそのやり方だけ学習して終わりだったのですが、今になって実用で使う時が来て、再び同じサイト様のページを見ながら行ったのですが、最後の最後で例の『クラスが見つからない』と出てしまいました。このブランク中に二回ほどPCも買い替えていますので、何かが変わっているのかもしれないのですが…。